# Beginner Python - I am not sure why the else statement is still being called in

Tags: python

```
x = 9
if x < 10:
    print("Too Small")
if x > 10:
    print("Too Large")
else:
    print("Just Right")
print("All Done")
```

When I run this and makin x equal to 11 it returns Too Large then all done, perfect.  When I make x equal to 10 it returns Just Right then all done, again perfect just what I wanted.  However when I make x equal to 9 it returns Too Small, then Just Right, then All Done.  I don't quite understand why the else statement is being called, if x is equal to 9 then I thought the program would skip the other if and else statement and go right to All Done.  What am I missing here?  Thank you.

Comment: You need to add `elif` to your second statement. See here https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_if_else.htm

Answer (score 2):

When you say:

```py
if condition:
   action
if condition:
   action
```

You are actually defining two completely independent conditions, the result of the test of the first condition will not change if the second condition is tested.

To "link" conditions so that later conditions are only checked if the first one fails you need to introduce an `elif`.

So if you do this:

```py
x = 9
if x < 10:
    print("Too Small")
elif x > 10:
    print("Too Large")
else:
    print("Just Right")
print("All Done")
```

You'll get the answer you expect.

Comment: That makes perfect sense now, thank you so much!

Comment: Thanks! If you found the answer helpful, please mark it at accepted!

Answer (score 0):

What you need is elif:

```
x = 9
if x < 10:
    print("Too Small")
elif x > 10:
    print("Too Large")
else:
    print("Just Right")
print("All Done")
```

You code is wrong because the way python works:

```
x = 9
if x < 10:
    print("Too Small") # it will print "Too small"


if x > 10:
    print("Too Large")
else:
    print("Just Right") # because 9 is not greater than 10, it will print "Just right"

print("All Done")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your else statement is linked to the second if statement, not the first one. So your first statement going through and then finishes and moves on. Try using an if else statement like this.

```
if x < 10:
    print("Too Small")
elif x > 10:
    print("Too Large")
else:
    print("Just Right")
print("All Done")
```